# Exit inside function on PHP

Tags: php, function, class, exit

Can I use this exit on a public api php OR it's an unsafe method?
I'm asking that because I want to show the error to api user without back to mainFunction.

```
class Apiclass{
    private extraPrivateFunction($var){
        if($var == 1){ 
          exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => 'error 1 is 1'))); 
        }
    }
    public mainFunction(){
        $number = 1;
        $this->extraPrivateFunction($number); 
    }
}
```

Thx guys.

Comment: can you? what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you perfectly can if you don't want to return to main.

Comment: Perfect scenario for custom error/exception handlers, or simply create a method to print an error.

Comment: Check out exceptions - it is a more graceful way to do the same thing.

Comment: Many thx guys!
I've tried it and works, I just need to confirm if it's not a unsafe method, cause third users will have access to this 'exit return'.

Comment: It is bad practice. Don't do it! Throw an exception, catch it in the code that generates the output and handle it there. It's not the responsibility of a class to decide the faith of the entire script. (Except when the purpose of the class is the handle the execution of the script. But such a class doesn't do any processing by itself, it only creates the appropriate collaborators and pass them the job).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, just try this code:

```
class Apiclass{
    private function extraPrivateFunction($var){
        if($var == 1){ 
          exit(json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message' => 'error 1 is 1'))); 
        }
    }

    public function mainFunction(){
        $number = 1;
        $this->extraPrivateFunction($number); 

        echo "Never Gets Here";
    }
}

$a = new Apiclass();
$a->mainFunction();
```